# How to make an SQLite database file created by an Electron App inaccessible to end users

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sqlite, electron

I am building an electron app that stores valuable user information in a SQLite database in either encrypted or hashed form. But the end-user will be able to access the database file easily and can view the structure and tables in the database. Isn't this undesirable. How do I prevent this? What are my options/strategies?

Answer (score 0):

Because the electron app is something that the user installs on his computer, he will have direct access to it, no matter what you do to it. You can obfuscate the process, but in the end a determined user will find what ever you are storing in that database.

Your best alternative is to use an api server to push and pull data to/from your server database, not on the user's computer.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am creating a password manager(a simple project so as to learn nodejs and electron). The whole point of it being a desktop application was to store sensitive material away from the web.